# Scrollable Frame Python Tkinter

Tags: python, scroll, tkinter

I am working n a project that has a scroll able frame. It lets me add widgets to the frame but I can not get the frame to scroll and show the rest of the widgets. I have compared my code to other scroll able frames online and I could not notice the difference. Any one see the solution.

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import os

class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    def gameView(self):
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self)
        self.mainFrame.pack(side=TOP)

        self.scroller = ttk.Scrollbar(self.mainFrame, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.scroller.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.mainFrame, bd=0)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

        self.viewArea = Frame(self.canvas, bg="Pink")
        self.viewArea.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroller.set)
        self.scroller.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.viewArea, anchor=NW, width=783, height=650)

        self.viewArea.bind("<Configure>", self.scrollCom)

        self.itemHolder = Frame(self.viewArea, bg="Pink")
        self.itemHolder.pack(side=TOP)

        self.gameGather()

    def scrollCom(self, event):
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"), width=783, height=650)

    def gameGather(self):
        for i in range(0, 50):
            label = Label(self.viewArea, text="Pie")
            label.pack(side=TOP)

root = Tk()
root.title("School Vortex 2.0")
root.geometry("800x650")
root.resizable(0,0)

gui = GUI(root)
gui.gameView()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would help if you created an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, is PIL really necessary to reproduce this problem? Is the menubar necessary?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes the menu bar and the image are needed because they are what is inside the scroll able area. And I use PIL for the image.

Comment: But is the image necessary to reproduce the problem? If you remove the image and insert a text label, does the problem still appear? If you remove the menu, does the problem still appear? Can't you simply create a loop that adds a bunch of labels or buttons to the frame for the purpose of debugging this problem? Also, what is `GameData`?

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok I remove all the unnecessary code. And the GameData is a empty class which I remove from the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put the window on the canvas you are explicitly giving it a height and a width. Because of that, the actual width and height of the frame is completely ignored. Because the frame is almost exactly the height of the canvas, there's nothing to scroll.

If you remove the `width` and `height` options from the call to `create_window` your frame will be scrollable.

Comment: That worked but now the things drawn in the canvas look like they are going under the scroll bar. Which is the image that I have in the frame